# Angular7 Use selected option in a select to set the options in another select

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have the following two select elements in my Angular 7 project:

[image]

My requirement is to populate the elements in the second select based on the value selected from the first select.
I have tried the following so far:

1. Used ngModel directive to get the the first selected value
2. Use the selected value to populate the items in the second the select element.

This is the code:
**app.component.html:**

```html
    <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Select Master Bot</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedMasterBot">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let masterBot of masterBotList" 
    [value]="masterBot.value">{{ masterBot.view }}</mat-option></mat-select> 
    </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
    <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Select UseCase</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedUseCase">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let useCase of 
    masterBotUseCaseMapping.selectedMasterBot" [value]="useCase.value">{{ 
    useCase.view}}
    </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-button (click)="print()">Click me</button>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```js
    public selectedMasterBot;
    public selectedUseCase;

    public masterBotUseCaseMapping = {
    "select1Value": [
    {
    "view": "incomprehension",
    "value": "incomprehensionID"
    },
    {
    "view": "greetings",
    "value": "greetingsID"
    }
    ], "select2Value": [
    {
    "view": "incomprehension",
    "value": "incomprehensionID"
    }
    ]
    }

    public masterBotList = [{
    view: 'select1',
    value: 'select1Value'
    },
    { 
    view: 'select2',
    value: 'select2Value'
    }]
```

Comment: Please take a look at Reactive Forms in Angular and you will like it instead of template driven forms.
There you can resolve this issue very trivially. You can subscribe on form control changes and get value, based on that value you can update selections list for the second select.

Comment: @Coffee-Tea I'm pretty new to Angular, sure I will have a look at reactive forms if it meets my requirement!

Comment: A plunkr or stackblitz would help find the issue

Comment: `selectedMasterBot` would get either `select1Value` or `select2Value` and this key is present nowhere in `masterBotUseCaseMapping`. THe mappings are incorrect

Comment: @Saksham I missed it while copying the code here. I have corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple use of `ngModel` can solve your problem of cascaded dropdown

Demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cascaded-dropdown

It looks like the mapping in your data is incorrect which you need to fix

Update fiddle https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wteh9o to support your data structure.

THe main issue here is that you are trying to access the property value ising `dot notation` whereas you should be using `array notation` as

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let useCase of 
masterBotUseCaseMapping[selectedMasterBot]" [value]="useCase.value">
```

Comment: It was a miss from my side, I have updated the question with the correct mapping. Please note that even with the correct mapping, I was facing the same issue

Comment: @TonyMathew added a new link per your data